# not working login form to display error in model window after server side validation in yii

Tags: ajax, validation, yii, modal-window, server-side-validation

I have a login form in modules which uses a chtml textfield which using jQuery does client side validation but if the user does not exist and enters both fields it redirect to the login url and does not display the error in a modal popup.

I am calling modules login via ajax in main layout. It can be in any page and calls the login perfectly.

but the only thing not WORKING is server side validations if login credentials are wrong. It redirects to the user/login page and not display the server side validation error in the modal window.

```
   <?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>

<div class="row1">

    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'username',array('placeholder'=>'Username or Email','class'=>'pclas')) ?>
</div>

<div class="row1">

    <?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($model,'password',array('placeholder'=>'Password','class'=>'pclas')) ?>
</div>


<div class="remsub">
<div class="rememberMe1">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeCheckBox($model,'rememberMe',array('class'=>"btn1"));echo CHtml::activeLabelEx($model,'rememberMe',array('class'=>"btn1"));  ?>
    <?php ?>
</div>

<div class="submit1">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton(UserModule::t("Login"),array('class'=>"btn")); ?>
</div>
 <div class="regpwd">
  <?php echo CHtml::link(UserModule::t("Register"),Yii::app()->getModule('user')->registrationUrl,array('class'=>'pclas1')); ?> | <?php echo CHtml::link(UserModule::t("Lost Password?"),Yii::app()->getModule('user')->recoveryUrl,array('class'=>'pclas1')); ?>

 < /div>    
</div>

  <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

```
    <?php
     $form = new CForm(array(
'elements'=>array(
    'username'=>array(
        'type'=>'text',
        'maxlength'=>32,
    ),
    'password'=>array(
        'type'=>'password',
        'maxlength'=>32,
    ),
    'rememberMe'=>array(
        'type'=>'checkbox',
    )
),

'buttons'=>array(
    'login'=>array(
        'type'=>'submit',
        'label'=>'Login',
    ),
),
   ), $model);


  ?>
```

and its a **LOGIN FORM** AND **NOT A** **SIGN UP FORM** is what my need is possible or any ohter solutions would be appreciated

Comment: Adding examples of your code would be of more help

Comment: have updated my question

Comment: yup i got it done working know :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please add your code so that we know what you're up to.

Some things that could help:

- Perhaps users who are using the form are **not allowed** to access the controller/action that does the validation? That would cause Yii to redirect him/her to login page. Try looking at the permissions for the controller/action that does the validation.
- Make sure your forms have enabled ajax validation:

  ```
  <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
      'id'=>'user-form',
      'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, <----------
      'enableClientValidation'=>true, 
      'focus'=>array($model,'firstName'),
  )); ?>
  ```

Comment: have updated my question and its not a registration form but then login form